# Надо ли ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы — помогаем вырасти вашему бизнесу.

Answer (score 3):

Только авторское интонационное  тире при определенном контексте, например:

Мы — ваши  верные помощники и друзья. Мы — советуем, как поступить. Мы — помогаем вырасти вашему бизнесу.

Answer (score 0):

Между подлежащим и сказуемым **никаких** знаков быть не должно, если эти члены предложения не разделены каким-либо оборотом, например, деепричастным, требующим обособления: «Мы, развиваясь сами, помогаем вырасти вашему бизнесу».